# Can not find northconcepts.datapipeline.jar

Tags: java-8

I am junior java developer and I am trying to test a data pipeline project given in this link

[> https://northconcepts.com/docs/examples/read-a-csv-file/](https://northconcepts.com/docs/examples/read-a-csv-file/)

in my local machine.

I get many errors that are generated such as :

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The import
> com.northconcepts.datapipeline.core.DataEndpoint cannot be
> resolved  ReadCsvFile.java    /ReadCSVFile/src/PipelineCSV    line 6  Java
> Problem

So, I think that I need to import jar files which are related to the imported libraries given in the code.

The problem is that I can not find online any jar file related to the northconcepts.datapipeline libraries to download and work with!
Any help, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is available [here](https://northconcepts.com/pricing/) but you need to register to download it (and pay for it, if you want something other than the free express version).

Comment: thank you . So not all jar are free here ! Well I can not test this code so

Answer (score 0):

You can test the code by following the getting started guide below to configure Maven/Gradle and get a license.  It should be pretty quick.

https://northconcepts.com/docs/user-guide/#getting-started

The examples are also [on GitHub](https://github.com/NorthConcepts/DataPipeline-Examples).